# Using PyLab's Specgram In A Headless Environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, headless

Anyone know how to get it working? Unfortunately it seems by default specgram's code wants to generate an image, which I have no use for, only the data behind the image. The error I get is:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set a matplotlib backend, which doesn't need a display attached:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('pdf')
```

These lines should go before importing `pylab`.

Comment: Great, I'll check it out tomorrow and see if it works.